# Why can not I see the screen output consecutively?

Tags: command-line, ls

When I run the `mkdir {2009..2011}-{1..12}` command, why can not I see it consecutively like `2009-1 2009-2 2009-3 ... 2009-12`?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Q0T.jpg]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listing is sorted lexically in columns. So `12` comes before `2`  because it sorts on the first digit (as if it were a word with `ab` coming before `b` in standard sorting) and `1` comes before `2`.

The normal way to handle this would be to include a leading zero on the single digits. `2009-01`, `2009-02`, ..., `2009-09`, `2009-10`. You can achieve this with `mkdir {2009..2011}-{01..12}`.

Comment: @whiskygsc If *Mark* could solve your problem, please *mark* his answer as such.